# How to add more rows to the default rows of a model in Active Admin, without rewriting them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I would like to add some extra rows in addition to all (default) rows of a model, in the `show` method of Active Admin.

Suppose I have *Appointment* model with the following attributes: `start_time` and `end_time`. Not specifying them in the `show` method of Active Admin displays them as rows, with additional information: `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` in addition to the default actions.

How can I add user name (for example) without re-writing the previous attributes. Actually I do the following:

```
show do
    # Rewrite default rows (how not to rewrite them?)
    row(:id)
    row(:start_time)
    row(:end_time)
    row(:created_at)
    row(:updated_at)

    # Add new row
    row(:user) { |appointment| appointment.user.name }
end
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

may be this can help, first get the default rows in the model, and loop through each of them. Then add any additional row required

```
 show do |appointment|
   rows = default_attribute_table_rows
   attributes_table_for appointment do
     rows.each do |column|          
       row column
     end  
     if appointment.user.present?
      row("user")  {appointment.user.name}
    end
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to lose default attributes (database columns) just do:

```
show do
  attributes_table(*resource.attributes.keys) do
    row "My new row description" do
      My row value
    end
  end
end
```

Your new row will be displayed at the bottom of the table